# How to delete hidden Column/Row from Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to delete all the hidden columns from Excel sheet and i am using `Microsoft Office Interop`. 
Problem is when i iterate through columns i didn't find the column hidden property set.
I don't know what am I doing wrong here.
Any help would be appreciated

```
int columnCount = wsCurrent.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
Excel.Worksheet wsCurrent = (Excel.Worksheet)wsEnumerator.Current;
for (int c = 1; c <= columnCount; c++)
{
    if (wsCurrent.UsedRange.get_Range((Excel.Range)wsCurrent.UsedRange.Cells[1, c], (Excel.Range)wsCurrent.UsedRange.Cells[wsCurrent.Rows.Count, c]).EntireColumn.Hidden)
        Console.WriteLine("Column Hidden");
}
```

Comment: I could give you a VBA code solution.. =/

Comment: You can share your solution, may be that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

By the way your code does not have "r" variable declaration which you are using.
Use next code to iterate cells and determine if cell is hidden:

```
const double SIZE = 0.5;
int cols = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
int rows = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
Range usedRange = sheet.UsedRange;
for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= cols; iCol++)
{
    for (int jRow = 1; jRow <= rows; jRow++)
    {
        Range cellRng = (Excel.Range)usedRange.Cells[jRow, iCol];
        if (double.Parse(cellRng.ColumnWidth.ToString()) <= SIZE ||
         double.Parse(cellRng.RowHeight.ToString()) <= SIZE)
        { 
            /*do your stuff here*/
        }
    }
}
```

Like this way. Constant Size is needed becouse cell could be **almost** hidden, but visualy it will be hidden. Code must be optimized, but concept is clear.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning 'r', changed it with 1.

Comment: I tried your code and when i debug it gives the same height and width for hidden cells as it is giving for visible ones. And secondly i feel it will not be efficient to do it like this. If there are 100s of sheets and each sheets has some thousands of rows and column.

Comment: Maybe your meening of hidden columns or hidden rows (accordingly hidden cells) is unlike mine. I checked code and cellRng.ColumnWidth returns 0 for cell in hidden column.